# What is the difference between a hardware carriage return and on-screen keyboard enter behaviour?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` followed by a `TextView`.

When using a hardware keyboard to enter text into the `EditText` and then pressing carriage return, the following `TextView` gets highlighted (its background changes to light grey). This does not happen when entering text using the on-screen keyboard and tapping the enter key.

I'd like to know how to make hardware input behave like soft input, i.e. not highlight the following `TextView`. Also, why does this happen in the first place? Highlighting does not happen when tapping/clicking the `TextView` (as expected).

What I already tried: I read https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input and changed `android:imeOptions` of the `EditText` to various values (actionDone, actionNone, normal), but this did not change the carriage return behaviour.